# sum value from a date range for a specific product

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am looking to sum up multiple values from multiple cells where they will match a date and a product.

like below: I have a date set in every cell in row 2 as below, and I have my categories in column A

[image: [display 1]]

now I want to pick the total value (that is unit costs) from (below picture) this sheet where the date is equal to 1-dec (date) and the category is equal to office.

[image: [display 2]]

I tried using this formula 
`( =sum(query(DataSheet!A3:J10, "select a,c,i where a= '"&C2&"' and c= '"&A4&"'",0),0) )`
 - but it is showing me a value error.

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: when I take off the iferror command it shown #N/A

Answer (score 0):

first you will need to fix those dates:

[image: 0]try:

then:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(QUERY(DataSheet!$A3:$J4, 
 "select J 
  where C = '"&$A4&"' 
    and A = date '"&TEXT(C$2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thank you - it is not showing any error now - but it is not returning any value either - just showing 0.

Comment: any idea how to fix this please ?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1joJdlLofwuhYE84j799-Q9jzUHSrSUWQWb1HPHARR4k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please see "O E Dec" sheet - trying to fetch values from "DataSheet"